# Aggregation and track back relations to multiple models in a single view Django

Tags: python, sql, django, database

I am doing first steps in Django and currently can't resolve further difficulties. Imagine we have next data scheme:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Inventories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique = True)
    unit = models.CharField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories)

class Suppliers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class InventoryReceiving (models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Inventories, related_name='item_received')
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Suppliers, related_name = 'item_supplier')
```

I would like to **group_by names in InventoryReceiving** to get distinct values and aggregated quantity fields. Then track back relations **and get a single grouped_by name table** with human readable **name, unit, category, supplier and quantity labels.**

I came up with an expression which return name_id (I need names from the related table) and sum:

```
inventory_list = InventoryReceiving.objects\
                     .values('name')\
                     .annotate(agg_sum=Sum('quantity'))
```

Comment: What about `name__name`  instead of `name` in `values()` ?

Comment: it is great advice, thank you! But I haven't found an explanation of usage `name__name` in django docs. Would you mind pointing me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just add the rest of the related data you need.

```
InventoryReceiving.objects.values(
    'name__name',           #Inventories.name
    'name__unit',           #Inventories.unit
    'name__category__name', #Inventories.category.name
    'supplier__name'        #Suppliers.name
).annotate(agg_sum=Sum('quantity'))
```

Comment: Great! It works. Thanks a lot. Would you mind pointing me at the part of django docs where usage of `name__name` is described? I haven't found it.

Comment: [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).  Its `name__name` because you named your `ForeignKey` as `name`. If it were something else, e.g. `inventory`, then it would be `inventory__name`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your advice was really helpful